# Some functions doesn't work without prototype, others do?

Tags: c, function, prototype

I'm trying to figure out why the functions `inperson` and `outperson` do not work without prototypes while the function `get` does. `Outperson` and `inperson` works without prototypes if I put them before the main-function but not after. The get-function works both before and after without a prototype. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct person {
   char name[100];
   int  age;
};

#define NPERSON 1

int main()
{
 //struct person inperson(void);
//void outperson(struct person p);
    struct person p[NPERSON];
    int i, oldest;
    for(i = 0; i < NPERSON; i++) {
          p[i] = inperson();
    }
    oldest = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < NPERSON; i++) {
          if(p[i].age > p[oldest].age) {
          oldest = i;
    }
}
outperson(p[oldest]);
get();

return 0;
}

int get()
{
    printf("works");
}

struct person inperson(void)
{
     struct person p;
     scanf("%s %d", p.name, &p.age);
     return p;
}

void outperson(struct person p)
{
     printf("Person %s, %d years, is oldest\n", p.name, p.age);
}
```

Comment: The specifics in this case are an interesting lesson in C-history. The short of it is that the default return type for function in C (unless there's a prototype that says otherwise) is int. So if your function return an int, most compilers will still handle it without complaining. You notice this is the case with the functions that work in your code.

Comment: Changed `int get()` to `void get()` and it didn't work. Thanks.